# How to save a user list to database asp.net web forms

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms

I want to save a user list to sql database the database table looks like this

```
Recipe_ID | Ingredient | Quantity
1         |  Tomato    |  2 Kg
1         |  Milk      |  1 Liter 
1         |  Salt      |  2 spoons
```

And so on so i want to save multiple rows from user and two columns. I don't Know how to get it from the user. I searched online and didn't find any answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code(view layer, data layer etc.) and explain where did you stuck.

Comment: @SelimYıldız   I'm stuck at the view layer , i tried to make two text boxes and input data to them but that didn't work so if i can make a solution on the view layer than the data layer is easy.

Comment: You need to show us what is not working and update question with your current codes.